# Is it possible to set a keyboard shortcut to a keyboard sequence?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like that I can get a list of my typescript functions using cmd-P @:
On my danish keyboard it is however clumsy to enter. Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to a keyboard sequence like cmd-P @:

Comment: A keyboard shortcut is assigned to a VSCode command. You can assign a different keyboard shortcut to it (or another one, without removing the old one) if you are not happy with the existing shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're accessing is "Go To Symbol in File" and it already has a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>shift+cmd+o</kbd> (Mac).

You can change it by going to your [keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), searching for the command, and then clicking the edit icon to the left of the result/command.

Comment: That helps a lot, but I still have to press : after shift+cmd+o . Is there a way to include : in a shortcut?

Comment: The `:` groups the symbols by category. As far as I know there isn't a command for that action directly (you could put in a feature request for it on GitHub, though). Another potential solution is to use a macro: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros